# Why doesn't this search box select all text on click?

Tags: javascript, html, yui

You can see the search box in question at: http://www.trailbehind.com. If the user tries to search twice, they have to press backspace a bunch to clear the text, but I'd like to select all text on double click, which inputs should do by default. Why doesn't mind?

When the users first clicks, I clear the input as follows:

```
input.onclick = clearInitialValue;

function clearInitialValue() { 
  this.value = ""; 
  this.onclick = 'return True';
  this.style.color = "black";
}
```

Another thing you might need to know to help me solve this riddle is that I used the input to instantiate a YUI autocomplete: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/, but I can't find anything in the docs that explains why double-clicking the input to select text wouldn't work.

Comment: if you are clearing the text onClick, how do expect to select text on dblClick? the frst click will always clear the text... what you can is clear the text if the text is equal to the initial text, for example.

Comment: Note that when they first click the input, it clears, and then the onclick function gets set to return true, instead of ClearInitial Value.

The following code also doesn't work for me:

<pre>
input.onfocus = clearInitialValue;

function clearInitialValue() { 
  this.value = ""; 
  this.style.color = "black";
  this.onfocus = 'return true';
}
</pre>

I am thinking now it's some interaction between the YUI autocomplete and the GMap.

Answer (score 1):

keep in mind that you can only have one method for each javascript event, so, in your example you are assinging the onclick event, make sure you do not do it again.

to have more you need to use an event listener.

```
var oDiv = document.getElementById('thediv');

oDiv.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    // your method here
}, true);
```

or simple

```
oDiv.addEventListener('click', clearInitialValue, true);
```

you metion that you are using YUI, so the code will be something like:

```
 YAHOO.util.Event.on(oDiv, "click", clearInitialValue);
```

not that answers your question directly, but keep in mind when dealing with javascript events.

---

to answer your question, your code runs great... check out the code running at [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/aziri)

you can add a /edit to the url in order to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your

```
  this.onclick = 'return True';
```

try

```
  this.onclick = 'this.select(); return true';
```

This will select the text in the box.

Consider doing this on focus, instead of click.

If that isn't behaving like you'd like, trying turning off the YUI autocomplete, to see if that is interferring. I've seen that.

If that doesn't do it, simplify more by implementing it on a clean page, with no other JS, before sticking it into the google map.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i see one thing that could be a problem, you have

```
this.onclick = 'return True';
```

try

```
this.onclick = 'return true';
```

javascript is case sensitive.